# Child view is never visible

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I'm building our UI programmatically and am having a bit of trouble getting elements to render for children views.

I am setting up the apps `Window` by instantiating my initial view controller and the view that it needs.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let initialView = StartupView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        let startupViewController = StartupViewController(startupView: initialView);

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);
        window!.rootViewController = startupViewController;
        window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible();

        return true
    }
}
```

The `StartupView` class instantiates a single `UIButton` that it adds to itself and sets constraints to specify the height/width and center align it horizontally and vertically.

```
class StartupView : UIView {

    // views
    var newAccountButton: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.configureView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.configureView()
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        self.newAccountButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.newAccountButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.newAccountButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.newAccountButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        self.newAccountButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        print("\(self.newAccountButton.titleLabel?.text ?? "Unknown") is \(self.newAccountButton.frame)")
        super.updateConstraints()
    }

    func configureView() {
        // New account button setup
        newAccountButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
        newAccountButton.titleLabel?.text = "Create Account"

        self.addSubview(newAccountButton)
    }
}
```

The `StartupView` is given to its `ViewController`. It would seem that the `ViewController` constraints assigned to the `StartupView` are working because I've verified that my `StartupView` does size itself to equal that of the `ViewController` view. When I run the simulator though, I don't see the `UIButton`.

```
class StartupViewController: UIViewController {
    var startupView: StartupView!

    init(startupView: StartupView) {
        self.startupView = startupView
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.startupView = StartupView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.startupView)

        self.startupView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.startupView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.startupView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.startupView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.startupView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        self.startupView.updateConstraints()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Am I doing the constraints wrong? Or does the order in which I add nested views matter?

### Edit

This is a screenshot of the view debugger.

[image]

I can see the button in the layout (highlighted) but I can't see the actual button being rendered. Writing `print("\(self.newAccountButton.titleLabel?.text): \(self.newAccountButton.frame)")` writes out the title of the button and it's frame but nothing is rendered.

Comment: You should never call `updateConstraints()` yourself. Instead you should call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` and let the layout engine take care of the rest. Furthermore make sure you don't add the same constrains again in `updateConstraints()` as this method can be called multiple times.

Comment: Thanks - I updated my code to use `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`. It didn't solve my original issue, but at least I know the proper way to request constraint updates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of overriding updateConstraints, you can simply do this:

#### Edit

Final solution (not accessing the label directly) after discussing in chat with OP:

```
    func configureView() {
        // New account button setup
        newAccountButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
        newAccountButton.setTitleColor(self.tintColor, for: UIControlState.normal)

        newAccountButton.setTitle("Create Account", for: UIControlState.normal)

        self.addSubview(newAccountButton)
        self.newAccountButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.newAccountButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.newAccountButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.newAccountButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        self.newAccountButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }
```

Comment: The button is still missing from the `StartupView` when the app runs :/ I also added `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` at the end of the `configureView()` function but it didn't make a difference

Comment: Did you remove self.startupView.updateConstraints() from StartupViewController viewDidLoad

Comment: I did - it didn't make a difference

Comment: Did you remove the updateConstraints method that you override

Comment: I did, I updated my OP to show a screenshot of the debugger as well. It looks like the constraints are working; nothing is rendered though.

Comment: Give the button some color, and check if you can see on the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150568/discussion-between-johnathon-sullinger-and-user1000).

Answer (score 0):

I think in your app delegate, you have to define size of your `StartupView`. Currently it's set to `zero`

```
let initialView = StartupView(frame: CGRect.zero).
```

Comment: The startup view gets its size set by the `StartupViewController` when it builds the `StartupView` constraints. That's working without issue